# A SDE with local lipschitz coefficient

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Since $\exp(\cdot)$ is local lipschitz, the following sde  has s strong solution
$$
\mathrm{d}X_s=\exp(X_s)\mathrm{d}B_s, X(0)=1,
$$
where $B$ is a Brownian Motion. I wander if the following expression holds?
$$\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^T\exp(2X(s))<\infty.$$

Comment: Yes, it admits a local-in-time unique strong solution since $x \mapsto \exp(x)$ is locally Lipschitz, i.e up to some random explosion time $e\left(\omega, X(0)\right)$ there exists a unique strong solution to your equation. For details, refer to Ikeda & Watanabe's _Stochastic Differential Equations and Diffusion Processes_ (particularly theorems 2.3 and 3.1 of chapter 4).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, and i also wander if $E \int _0^T \exp(2X(s))\mathrm{d}s<\infty$?

Comment: For $T$ large enough no. Set $u(t,x) = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(2X(t))|X(0) = x\right]$, then a computation using the generator shows that $$\partial_t u(t, x) = \mathbb{E}\left[2\exp(4X(t))|X(0) = x\right] \geq 2\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(2X(t))|X(0) = x\right]^2 = 2(u(t,x))^2.$$ We can lower bound $u$ by $\phi$ the solution of the following equation $$\partial_t \phi(t,x) = 2\left(\phi(t,x)\right)^2 \quad \phi(0, x) = u(0, x).$$ Solving this equation shows that for fixed $x$, $\phi(t,x) \to \infty$ as $t \to \frac{1}{2\phi(0, x)}$.  Thus if $T\geq \exp(-2X(0))/2$ the integral expression is not finite.

Comment: I get that, thanks!